# After upgrading from 13.04 to 13.10 I cannot get any image to display on the login screen, why?

Tags: 13.04, upgrade, 13.10

I can login in without any issue & can display any image as my wallpaper. But the default image does not display. I've even tried using ubuntu-tweak to change the image, but all that is displayed is a plain black screen, with the user list.

I've tried looking at dmesg, Xorg.0.log, syslog, user.log, but can find no indication as to what is the cause. So can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Do you just want to change the login screen background?

Comment: I have the same problem. On 13.04. lightdm would show the current wallpaper on the login screen (a.k.a. dynamic background). 13.10. doesn't and only shows the solid dark purple color (with the dots on top). Is this expected behavior?

Comment: In my `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.canonical.unity-greeter.gschema.xml` "draw-user-backgrounds" is set to true. Changing the path for "background" doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 2):

To change the login screen background of the lighdm login manager:

1. First backup the configuration file:

   ```
   sudo cp /etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf /etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf.old
   ```
2. Then edit it, changing `background=CURRENT-IMAGE.jpg` to `background=LOCATION-OF-WANTED-BACKGROUND-IMAGE.jpg`

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf
   ```
3. Then test it, by running:

   ```
   sudo lightdm --test-mode
   ```

Comment: Did not have any effect for me. Probably because I'm using the unity greeter.

Comment: It may be using one of the other config files in `/etc/lightdm/`, so edit the other ones and see what happens. Also, lightdm is the default anyway, and there is also a manual page [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM).

Answer (score 1):

*Give this a try...*

Add the user localuser:lightdm to the access control list.

- `sudo xhost +SI:localuser:lightdm`

Now using `su`, change/log-in as the user *lightdm*;

- `sudo su lightdm -s /bin/bash`

Now to turn off the grid of white dots use:

- `gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter draw-grid false`

To set a unity-greeter default background:

- `gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter background [YOUR_BACKGROUND_IMAGE]`, YOUR_BACKGROUND_IMAGE could be in your Pictures folder or /usr/share/backgrounds, where I keep it, or from wherever the system can access. Make sure the image file has read permissions set.
  e.g.
  `gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter /usr/share/backgrounds/myWelcomeScreen.jgp`
  And then `chmod 444 /usr/share/backgrounds/myWelcomeScreen.jgp` to make it readable to all users.

To set your desktop wallpaper for greeter screen:

- `gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter draw-user-backgrounds true`

Next time the greeter screen should appear the way you want it to.